# Child shell script didn't respond to terminal interrupt sent to the foreground process group

Tags: shell-script, shell, signals

I have a master script that controls some satellite scripts. When I send the interrupt signal from the terminal, the parent's `trap`s caught the signal, but the child's didn't, which I can't figure out why. I didn't change the default terminal setting (I didn't run `stty` anywhere).

Here's my parent and child script and terminal output:

parent:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

./child.sh &

for sig in $(kill -l) ; do
    trap "echo parent:$sig" $sig
done

wait
```

child:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

cat < /dev/tty &
PID=$!

for sig in $(kill -l) ; do
    trap "echo child:$sig" $sig
done

wait
```

terminal interaction:

```
[prompt]$ ./parent.sh
^Cparent:INT
cat: stdin: Input/output error

[prompt]$
```

**Update**

I tested the script on macOS and CentOS, the behavior describe above occurs. When I test it on FreeBSD using the default Bourne-compatible shell, the signal child receives is `CHLD`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For commands run asynchronously by non-interactive shells (actually when job control is not enabled), SIGINT and SIGQUIT are ignored in POSIX compliant `sh` implementations. That's [a POSIX requirement](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11) though some shells ignore it.

[Another POSIX requirement](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap) is that if a signal was ignored upon start of the shell, you can't unignore it, so you're screwed.

Here, you could use `zsh` instead of `sh` which doesn't have either of those annoying "features" (at least in current versions).

In any case signal handling in shells is one of the least reliable and portable aspects. You'll find behaviours vary greatly between shells and often between different versions of a same shell. Be prepared for some serious hair pulling and head scratching if you're going to try to do anything non-trivial.

I'd recommand using a different language where you can have a finer control over what happens.

Also, I wouldn't blindly handle every possible signal, only the ones you're expecting to receive and know how you can handle. Trapping SIGCHLD for instance (which the shell itself is interested in as it's its job to spawn processes and handle their termination) is likely not to do what you want.

Comment: @zevzek, that very much depends on the shells, some use `wait*()`, some use a handler on SIGCHLD and get the info from siginfo_t. For having tested a few years ago, IIRC, some let you trap SIGCHLD, some don't.

Comment: @zevzek, what I meant was that it was unlikely to do what you want whatever it is. You can try `"$shell" -c 'trap uname CHLD; id; exit'` and compare between shells. You'll find some run `uname` in a loop, some don't run it at all, some run it once.